# If statement to check for post_content

Tags: conditional-content, post-content

I'm trying to write an if statement to check for post_content and if there is no post_content then to grab a textarea field content. Below is my code and with this, at this point it's only rendering "Array" to the page. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**CODE:**

```
<?php
foreach ($partners as $partner) {
  $a_description = get_post_meta($partner->ID, "a_description");
?>

  <div class="partner-content">
    <?php
      if ($partner->post_content && !$a_description) { ?>
        <?php echo $partner->post_content  ?>
      <?php } else { ?>
        <?php echo get_post_meta($partner->ID, $a_description, true); ?>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Please correct your syntax. Never use shorttags. Use proper opening and closing php tag, for example either `<?php` or `?>`

Comment: @PieterGoosen as in `<?php echo $partner->post_content  ?>`?

Comment: Correct. Shorttags are annoying as not all enviroments are setup for those. As soon as someone copy the content to their test enviroment to test the code, they immediatly get a parse error. Annoying to first go and correct something simple like php tags

Comment: @PieterGoosen thanks for that :) I am new to PHP and Wordpress and love to know what is best practices. I'm still wondering how to get the if statement to work though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line is wrong

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($partner->ID, $a_description, true); ?>
```

If you look closely, you are actually passing

```
get_post_meta($partner->ID, "a_description")
```

to the `$key` parameter of [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) as this is the value assigned to `$a_description`

You should most probably change `$a_description` to just `a_description`

**EDIT**

This line

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($partner->ID, $a_description, true); ?>
```

should most probably be

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($partner->ID, 'a_description', true); ?>
```